# Ubuntu 16.04 with AMD Radeon HD-6450 - what are my options?

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

I've just upgraded to 16.04 and my graphics card, AMD Radeon HD-6450, isn't holding up so well. I can't use my dual screens, and cannot adjust the warped screen resolution.

What are my options?